# issue in scanning the percentage in Java

Tags: java, percentage

i'm trying to teach myself Java language and actually i have a problem with an exercise task which i need to add the percentage of the interest in a code where i can calculate the amount in the end of the loop .
How can i tell the program to take the scanned interest value as a "percentage" and use it to loop as i'm trying to do? .

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int amount;
    int year=0;
    double interest=0;

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("What is the amount?");
    amount = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("How much is the interest");
    interest= sc.nextDouble();
    while(amount <= 2000)
    {
    year++;
    interest =amount*(interest/100);
    amount =(int) (amount+interest);

    }

    System.out.println("amount"+amount);
    System.out.println("year"+year);
```

Comment: Thats makes the percentage here `(interest/100);` Whats wrong? I only guess `amount =(int) (amount+interest);` here you lost precision where you should not to.

Comment: `double interest` should actually be `double rate` - first of all. Or create another variable for interest. And if you want it to be directly used as percentage, then don't divide it by 100. In that case, input would be something like 0.12 if rate is say 12%.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply change the loop like this and avoid having to change the interest variable value:

```
while(amount <= 2000)
{
    year++;
    amount = (int) (amount + (amount*(interest/100)));
}
```